# Executing multiple user inputs bash

Tags: bash

I am writing bash script in which it asks for specific directory and makes it while executing script.
Then it asks me for number of persons and goes in for loop. I want it to then make a text file with directory and name of person entered.

When it comes to make a file using touch it doesn't work.

Am I missing something.

```
echo "Please enter directory\n"    
read -p directory    
mkdir -p $directory/name    

echo "Please enter number of persons\n"    
read -p number    

for ((i = 0; i <= number; i++))    

do     
    echo "Please enter person $i :\n"    
    read -p person    
    touch $directory$person.txt    

done
```

Comment: Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45631651/edit) to highlight what the actual problem is? What is not working for you?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited to highlight the problem.

Comment: @Mike, have you managed to solve this? Have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several issues.

First of all, you're not reading user input properly. The `-p` option of the `read` command is used to provide a text that will serve as a prompt, not to specify the output variable. The output variable is given as a positional argument. So, for example you can read user input into variable `directory` without a text prompt (then you probably need `echo` before) like this: `read directory`; or you can print the prompt and read like this: `read -p "Directory: " directory`.

Secondly, your loop iterates `number+1` times, from `0` to `number`, inclusive. You probably want it to go from `1` to `number`.

Lastly, the name of the output file you're `touch`ing is not necessarily the file inside the `$directory`, but it could be a file in your current working directory. For example if user enters `somedir` for `directory`, and `name` for `person`, then you'll create a file named `somedirname.txt`. So, it's best to put a slash between a directory name and a file name.

With these fixed, your script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter directory: " directory
mkdir -p "$directory/name"

read -p "Please enter number of persons: " number

for ((i = 1; i <= number; i++)); do
    read -p "Please enter person $i: " person
    touch "$directory/name/$person.txt"
done
```

Running it for example like this:

```
$ bash script
Please enter directory: /tmp
Please enter number of persons: 3
Please enter person 1: Huey
Please enter person 2: Dewey
Please enter person 3: Louie
```

will create a directory `/tmp/name`, and files in it:

```
$ find /tmp/name
/tmp/name
/tmp/name/Huey.txt
/tmp/name/Dewey.txt
/tmp/name/Louie.txt
```